# 317-325Hz signal with probes detached on JYE Tech DSO Shell

Tags: oscilloscope, oscillation

[image]

The picture shows DSO Shell JYEtech (in a custom battery powered enclosure - for convenience) with probes shortened (same occurs if probes are not attached at all) with a what appears as a stable sawtooth-like signal of around 317-326Hz. **Gain control on the device don't affect apparent amplitude of the signal**. Please help to diagnose the cause of this.

Comment: take the DSO for a walk down the street ... eliminate possible causes in immediate area

Comment: I would take it down the street and deposit it in a recycling bin, but that's me. Save your money for a decent 'scope like a Rigol. WAG is that the LM1117 regulator is oscillating because they used a ceramic cap without a series resistor.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be induced EMF. The signal is there regardless of the device location/orientation or input gain settings. I even tried shielding the analog board - no change in amplitude. Oscilloscope still shows input signals, but they are heavily modulated by 325Hz. Come to think of it, cycle is suspiciously close to 3.14.